# Marketplace V2 License API returned user as licensed (active) in organization not included

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

During the install flow of my Marketplace V2 application, I only granted access to one of the organizations (orgUnits) in the google account. The more menu (nine dots) correctly seems to exclude my app from users not in the granted organization BUT when I do a user license query (https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/userLicense/get) for those users who are not in the granted organization, I am still getting 'ACTIVE' rather than 'UNLICENSED'.

LT

Comment: Any insights from google folks? Further testing showed that for those users in org units which have not been granted access, if we try to set the user in the Service Account as one those users and make API calls then this is not allowed. So if this license API doesn't work as I'm expecting, then the only way it seems to programatically find out if a user has access is to make a test call with a Service Account with that user.

Answer (score 0):

On further testing, the "enabled" field which is described in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/userLicense#resource) as:

enabled   boolean   The domain administrator has activated the application for this domain.

Seems to return the enabled status of the app for the org unit that the user is in rather than the entire domain. So this field actually gives the answer I want in terms of whether the app is enabled for the user (or more precisely enabled for the org unit that the user is in).

LT